# Shortcoming of -a Switch with git commit

Tags: git

`git commit -a -m 'blabla'`

I have noticed that `-a` switch does sometimes not add all files or folders like it does with

`git add . --all`

Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Look at `man git-commit` and the `-a, --all` option. It says that `git commit -a` ignores files git doesn't already know about.

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is `-A` instead of `-a`...

Answer (score 2):

`git commit -a` ignores files git doesn't already know about, e.g. new files, moved files or directories.

More explanation can be found with

`man git-commit` and looking at the `-a` and `--all` option.